# Notepad++ collapse level with Python code

Tags: python, notepad++

I find the collapse level (Alt+1, Alt+2, etc) functionality of Notepad++ extremely handy, but only the first level (Alt+1) seems to work for Python code. Manually collapsing a single code block works fine at any level, so it's not like Notepad++ can't handle the indentation-driven syntax.

Does anyone know of a plugin or maybe a setting I missed that would allow this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this to "Settings->shortcut mapper", and you have to do is "alt+1+2" (without releasing alt) all function of a class is collapsed 
[image: Shortcut Mapper]

tecnically is fold all then unfold 1st level

Comment: This is a really neat solution. I altered it a little to use Alt+~ for Fold All, leaving 1-9 to map to the corresponding level while still keeping everything within easy reach. Thanks!

Comment: well it seems useless because that is a bugs of notepad++ that cannot fold/unfold level 2 and up, this is the ticket http://ehc.ac/p/notepad-plus/bugs/2601/

Comment: Hahaha. Well, we get one extra level of folding out of it at least :).

Answer (score 2):

You're right. Python collapse by shortcuts is only at level 1. There isn't any visible setting to fix that. Browsing at plugins page I didn't found anything. Maybe that folding issue is a bug. I suggest you to use [Support & online help](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/support-online-help) to get an explanation and/or solution, or submit a [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=95717&atid=612382) if you can't find that.

Comment: It turns out there is an open bug report (actually, two) regarding this issue. Thanks.

Comment: `alt+5` folds 2nd level
https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/1898